# HTML Email jump links not working

Tags: html, email, outlook, anchor

I've written a HTML Email using tables (:sad face:) and it displays perfectly while using Internet Explorer's Send -> Page by Email. My issue is that my jump links

```
<a href="#jumplink">Go to the jump link</a>
```

no longer work, thye just open the complete URL of the page that I was sending. I've looked through the source of emails in which the jump links do work and I saw that the jumps links looked like this

```
<a href="BLOCKED::#wordtag">Word generated jump link</a>
```

I tried adding this but I'm still getting IE opening and it's now going to http:///

Any idea if there's any extra tags I need to add or another way to get around this?

Comment: are you trying to solve this for your users so that they can use IE to send a page by email? or are you trying to use IE as a way to create HTML emails that you want to send? - if the latter, this is not a good approach.

Comment: in addition what email client are you sending with? e.g. Outlook/Outlook express will potentially alter your content in ways that say Thunderbird would not.

Comment: The person who will be using this will only have access to IE6 and Outlook (I work in the UK's NHS so installation of Mozilla stuff is pretty much out of the question :( ) Is there a better way to take an HTML file and get it into outlook? I'm using this method because apart from the jump links everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, this is something that has to do with the way Microsoft deals with Internet Security. It is best practice to avoid named (jump) anchors in HTML email, unfortunately. However, to overcome this you might want to provide a link to a webpage with the HTML email on, which can of course have named anchors.

You can read more about best practices for email design on [this article at Sitepoint](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters/). There is also a great resource for HTML email design at the Email Standards Project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!!
In outlook -> new email->attach file->insert(select the html file here)->insert as text(dropdown on the insert)
Which will make the jump links work.
but the problem is all with the active links and visited link color. Doing this leave you no control over visited and active link colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the email template as signature.
Open the tempalte in IE and click CTRL+A to copy the page.

Create a signature and Page the content as it is.

Create a New email and insert the Signature. The template will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When trying to send a html page using Internet Explorer's Send -> Page by Email, the anchor pointed to the url of the webpage instead of to the internal link in the mail.

This can be solved by adding this in the head of the page:

```
<base href="" />
```